# Flutter integration test pull down notification bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Is there any way to pull down the notification bar during an integration test?

If so, is there a way to interact with a certain notification? For example, click on it?

Comment: are you targeting android for the test case?

Comment: @Darish for now, yes.

Comment: Currently it is not available for the Flutter driver API, but you can do so by adding native code to the android specific directory. See this for more info https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing

Comment: @Darish is there a way to integrate this with the fullter integrationtest? For now I just want to take a screenshot of it.